# Is there a way to sync applications having kafka stream to avoid duplicate message processing?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In my spring boot application, I utilized kafka streams. It first groups messages from a certain topic by key, windows them according to certain time interval, uses reduce to keep only the latest message for every key and processes and sends the latest message in the time window for every key to another queue at the end of the time window.

```
stream.groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(window)
        .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue, materialized)
        .toStream()
        .process(() -> /*process and send message to a queue*/);
```

It works fine with only one instance but when number of instances increases, every instance processes same messages and at the queue, I see multiple messages for same key for same time window.

I want only one message corresponding to a key in time interval. I aim to have that if an instance works with messages with a key, the other instances should not process messages for this key. Is there any possible way to do that without a custom implementation on message processing logic?

Comment: _other instances should not process messages for this key_ - That's just builtin to Kafka consumer protocol. Equal keys exist in one partition and only one consumer at a time can read any partition

Comment: The problem is that for some reason we subscribe to the queue per machine not per application so that causes the duplications.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things you need to consider:

1. Kafka Streams assumes that input data is partitioned by key. If that's not the case, you would need to replace `groupByKey()` with `groupBy((k,v) -> k))`  or `repartition().groupByKey()`. If data is not partitioned by key, you might get multiple windows for a single key.
2. Kafka Streams does by default not emit a single "final" result for a windowed aggregation, but it continuously refines the result as long as the window is open, and emits intermediate results. If you want a single result per window, you can use `.reduce(...).suppress(...)` or `.windowBy(...).emitStrategy(...)` (checkout the docs for details about both options).

Comment: The input data is partitioned by key and I only get one window for a single key. There is no problem on that. My main issue is that stream beans in different instances on different machines of same application doesn't know each other. Is there any possibility to configure the connection between the instances and kafka so that for one key only one instance works and others will work with other keys?

Comment: `so that for one key only one instance works and others will work with other keys` -- if you input data is partitioned by key, and you get one window per key, what you ask about is already happening. Why do you think that a single key is processed by different instances?